# How can I have multiple fills within the same d3 arc

Tags: css, d3.js

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

In d3.js. I can draw the donut chart fine but I'm struggling on how I can have multiple colors within an arc. Is there a way I plot multiple arcs within the same arc and style them independently?

Comment: It sounds like you want a [gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) with hard stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting multiple colors within a single arc, I would recommend having a single arc for each color. This way, if your data changes, you can just change the lengths of each arc, rather than changing the gradient you're using.

A good example of this is here: [d3 gallery donut chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193)